# Xquartz Catalina hangs

Tags: terminal, homebrew, x11

I've had Xquartz working multiple times on different machines over the years but I just did a new install and have some strange behavior with no windows popping up.

My issue is, when I run an app like xclock, it just hangs acting like it's running but no window pops up.  And when I try to quit Xquartz it goes away initially but then comes back after a few seconds.  Even force quit doesn't kill it, it comes back after a few seconds.  Then trying to quite the terminal session, it says Xquartz is still running though `killall X11` says:

> "No matching processes belonging to you were found"

I installed Xquartz via homebrew and manually with the .dmg file and restarting my computer, still same issue. I saw someone said to delete the X11 .plist files in your User Library but that didn't work.

I can click on /Applications/Terminal and it works but the functionality I am used to in the terminal doesn't seem to be working.

I have added `/opt/X11/bin:` to my path so I can execute the xcommands anywhere.

Xquartz assigned my environment variable to `DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.07dUzDaTi1/org.xquartz:0`

Any suggestions to troubleshoot would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I remember having that problem as well a while ago. If you create a new user account on your Mac and run X11 there, does it work?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my problem by downloading the latest beta version found here: https://www.xquartz.org/releases/index.html